Output/Input Impedance of Common Emitter BJT with feedback
I am designing an oscillator circuit (Pierce topology) based on the book "Foundations of Oscillator
Circuit Design" by Guillermo González.
This the theoretical schematic:

It is made up of two circuits:

The amplifier stage (NPN BJT with voltage divider bias)
The feedback circuit (crystal with bth \$C_{1}\$ and \$C_{2}\$ as load capacitors.

In order for the circuit to oscilate, the gain of the amplifier \$A\$ and feedback circuit \$B\$ must be: \$A\cdot B>1\$ .
For the feedback circuit this task is easy, as it is a simple voltage divider with complex impedances.
However, for the transistor section (I know there are other ways to find the gain), but if someone was to calculate the gain using output/input impedances, how could it be done mathematically?
Considering the input impedance (AC) (no feedback, open loop):
$$
Z_{in} = R_{1} || R_{2} || h_{ie}\cdot\beta
$$
And for the feedback impedance:
$$
Z_{out} = Z_{1} || \left(Z_{XTAL} + Z_{2}\right)
$$
My main question is:

In the common emitter configuration, the gain can be calculated using \$Gain = -g_{m}\cdot Z_{L}\$; with \$Z_{L} \rightarrow\$ output impedance. **Is this "\$Z_{L}\$" the sum of \$Z_{in} + Z_{out}\$ ?.

$$
Z_{L} = Z_{in} + Z_{out}
$$
Thanks in advance.

Are you reading the same book I have here, from 2006/2007? What section are you reading? (I'm looking at 4.4.) Where did that diagram you show come from? (The book does discuss $Z_L$, fairly clearly.)
